Property filter syntax in GeoTools
I am using GeoTools filter to query data:
String park_id = 'xxxxx'; //got from requset
Filter f = FF.equal(FF.property("park_id"), FF.literal(park_id));
SimpleFeatureCollection featuresInPark = store.getFeatureSource("landuse").getFeatures(f);

However the featuresInPark was always empty. I have tried that:
Filter f = FF.equal(FF.property("park_id"), FF.literal("'" + park_id + "'"));

Nothing changed.
And It is certain that layer landuse contains attribute park_id. Also for a given park_id the desired result will be filtered in QGIS.
So I am afraid my filter syntax may be wrong.

Finally,through debugging into the source code, I found that one have to add the third parameter for the filter:
Filter f = FF.equal(FF.property("park_id"), FF.literal(park_id),true);

Without the third parameter, the expression will be considered as Geometry equal instead of attribute equal.

From further study of the FilterFactory code it looks like you could use equals
